# How to make inline expanding header with ellipsis overflow

Tags: html, css

I've got the following layout:

```
<article>
    <h3><a>...</a></h3>
    <h3><a>...</a></h3>
</article>
```

The first header has dynamic content, the second has a fixed width set.

I'd like the headers to be inline, and when the content of the first one grows, for it to stretch until the sum of both headers' widths is 100%, and then for overflow text to be ellipsis.

I've been running into the problem of once I make the first div inline or float, its width no longer stays contained by the parent, making text overflow everywhere, or with overflow set to hidden, I can't get the second header to be positioned on the same line with it.

P.S.: Unfortunately this will need to support as many old browsers as possible, back to I.E. 6 would be the best (/barf) but whichever solution reaches as far back as possible will be the most valuable. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question right, it's easily achievable with [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```
article {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
article > h3:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}
article > h3:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aLuJUBip/3/edit).

Comment: Too bad it still [sucks the browser support right now](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes what is the browser support you're looking for?

Comment: It really depends on what browsers @Charles targets. He may as well develop for node-webkit for all we know.

Comment: Firefox uses the old implementation, as does IE10. Right now, in a nutshell, less than 50% of the common browsers support it right, and less than 75% support it at all. While your sample will actually work fine in 'old implementation' 75% is in my book not yet 'fit for production deployment'. Should be within half a year though.

Comment: Unfortunately the user base is old, so I need to support browsers as old as possible... @Klaster_1 I really like seeing how this would be done in a modern way though, thank you for this answer

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the issue properly, the following JSFiddle may have the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/modenadude/QntUm/2/

The code:

- keeps the two `<h2>`s inline
- if the width of the first `<h2>` gets wider than the width of the second `<h2>` + `<article>`'s width, it adds the ellipses to the first `<h2>`

I set `max-width` on the `<h2>`s (to 50%) just in case, and added `outline` to show the widths clearly.

*I used jQuery to figure out the widths of the `<h2>`s onload, but the same can be done with pure JS by using `getElementByID` (I can set that up too if you'd like). And of course it was designed to be used on only two `<h2>`s and one `<article>` so simple editing could make it more expandable.*

Comment: This is a good attempt, though I was hoping for a pure CSS answer, and the width limit is not quite what I was going for.